# Scanning a "Bit Pattern" for matching a integer

Tags: java, bit

I want to create a method that "scans" an integer for a BitPattern like `110` and return the result as a boolean.

For example:

- BitPattern is set to `110`
- integer bits is set to `2461` (in Bit: `00001001 10011101`)

The BitPattern matches with the integer and returns `true`

```
0000100110011101 -> integer 

       110       -> Bitpattern
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The correct spelling is "integer" not "interger" BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab at it, haven't tested...

```
public boolean isMatchBitPattern(int target, int pattern) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
       if (((target >> i) & pattern) == pattern) {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Maybe* faster, or maybe not:

```
public boolean isMatchBitPattern(int target, int pattern) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32 && target != 0; i++) {
       if ((target & pattern) == pattern) {
          return true;
       }
       target >>= 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This version will exit early if there are no more '1' bits remaining in the target being tested.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i try to solve it with while with a "limit", set to the most significant bit.

Comment: I will only consider bits right side from the most "significant bit".

Comment: Updated answer that stops when the most significant bit has been reached.

Comment: Try it. For my example 2461 as "target" and a "pattern" set to 110 i get "false". But: 2461 as integer is given as 00001001 10011101  what includes the pattern 110. Thanks alot

Comment: ``isMatchBitPattern(2461, 6)`` returned ``true`` for me.  6=110, 2461=00001001 10011101.

Comment: Yes thats true, but isMatchBitPattern(2461, 110) returned false.

Comment: "110" is not a binary number, it is the number one hundred and ten.  If you need to do that use  isMatchBitPattern(2461, Integer.parseInt("110", 2)).

Comment: Therefore i want to use the most significant bit in order the get binäry digits. the method to find it is already done

Comment: ok logical fault. i get it. Thanks brettw